# UriMatcher equivalent helper for web apps?

Tags: google-app-engine, url, matching

I have coded a lot of Android App and many times, I have used the UriMatcher class to match both conetent uris and http urls.

Now I am working on a little web app using Java and Gae. I have little servlet that need to match calls agains DYNAMIC info. Not static url patterns, but runtime parse data.

In Android, UriMatcher would have been my chioce, but what is available in the Java Se World?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use Java Servlet API on GAE and register it to receive a wildcard Uris, then [resolve](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestURI%28%29) and map Uris:

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws IOException {
        String uri = req.getRequestURI();
        // do something with the uri here

        // generate a response
        resp.setContentType("text/plain");
        resp.getWriter().println("Hello, world");
    }
}
```

and register it:

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>My servlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.package.MyServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>My servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Yeah, but that is not what I want. I want to match a certain set of urls, based on some information, only known at run-time (I am building a proxy-thingy). So, I want to build a servlet that intercepts the requests and checks if they match a certain pattern.


lets say


<id>/path/
<id>/path/<sub-id>
<id>/path/<sub-id>/subpath


matches any incomming request, then I want to forward the request  to another app (with <id> in the url).

The different paths that I want to match is only known at runtime.

Comment: Yes, wildcard `*` catches all requests, then you parse Uri in code and forward further.

Comment: Exactly, but my question is about the last part of your sentence, parsing the Uri an process it further. I am looking for utility to do the processing (matching). Is there nothing more than RegExp around? It feels a bit low-level....